# why won’t the hsv v scale go any higher than 1

Tags: color

When using a color ramp to make something glow, and I had planned to use the the bloom function. But when I turned up the v scale it went back to 1.000 and wouldn’t go any higher. And when I turned on bloom it didn't glow. Pls send help.

Comment: HSV is a color description system, where v stand for *value*. They all stay in 0~1 for manipulating. You can't change the color space definition by changing the hsv value outside it's scope. Could you provide more information on what you want hsv and color ramp for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values in HSV nodes in both the Compositor and Shader Editor can go above 1:

[image]

1 means 100%. If we are talking about color information in an image 1 represents 100% of some color channel - the most it can be so it cannot go any higher, however color in Blender is 32bit so it can be pretty much any value. The dynamic range of colors can be a lot greater than it can be displayed in an image inside Blender. Colors of a render can be adjusted the way you want them to fit into an image - that's color grading. Anyway, you can definitely go above 100% or 1 in Blender in value of HSV nodes. It is not a good idea in some cases though as it might make your renders unrealistic.